# What is the standard way of naming source files in C?

Tags: c, naming-conventions

Is there a standard way of naming source code files in C?

E.g. Should they be underscore separated, capitalized, camel case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no mandatory convention.  In part, it depends on whether your system has a case-sensitive or case-insensitive file names.

The `.c` suffix (lower-case) is essentially universal for source files, and the `.h` for header files.  Other files included in source files may have different extensions, or no extension at all.

Classically, the names were all lower-case (look at the standard header names, for example).  The names avoid accented characters, spaces and many other punctuation characters, usually adhering to the [portable filename character set](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_276) (alphanumerics, underscore, dash, dot).  Other than that, the choice is largely up to you.

Answer (score 15):

There is no standard, but many C projects use lowercase filenames, separating words with underscores. The main thing is to be consistent though.

Answer (score 1):

As the other person mentioned, there's no standard when it comes to naming the source files. It purely depends on the convention followed by the team / organization / group. I have come across many projects that use lowercase letters and camel cased letters.

helloworld.c
HelloWorld.c